# how to configure mongodb to start with additional parameters

Tags: mongodb

I'm running mongodb on Ubuntu 14.
I would like to be able to automatically start mongod with

```
--rest
```

flag

Where do I specify that?

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/init/mongo.conf - add --rest to the list of DAEMON_OPTS